# Is it possible to host site at wordpress but have it reachable by mydomain.com/blog? What are SEO implications of this?

Tags: wordpress, seo, domain-mapping

I have a blog currently hosted at mydomain.wordpress.com but reachable by blog.mydomain.com and have been told this is not helping my SEO credibility. I've been told to switch to mydomain.com/blog but don't know if I can point a subdirectory at a site hosted elsewhere. Is this possible? Will it actually improve my SEO ranking/credibility?

**Current Setup**

```
//Hosted at:
mydomain.wordpress.com

//Domain Mapped to:
blog.mydomain.com
```

**Desired Setup**

```
//Hosted at:
mydomain.wordpress.com

//Domain Mapped to:
mydomain.com/blog
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to implement a 301 (permanent) re-direct from the subdomain to mydomain.com/blog subfolder. Having your blog on a subfolder will help you immensely because your blog is currently being seen as a separate site. None of the links or credibility from your domain flow to your blog while it is on your subdomain and vice versa.

If you have the blog on your main site

- It will be adding fresh and unique content to the site
- It will bring more inbound links to the site (the links to your subdomain don't help your main domains ranking)
- It will provide you with a greater ability to generate rich keywords for the sites ranking.

These all add a lot of SEO value to the site. With your blog hosted on your subdomain, it will not be providing any added value to your site.

Comment: But with a 301 redirect, won't I need to be hosting the blog physically at mydomain.com/blog? This isn't the same thing as it being hosted at wordpress but pointed to by mydomain.com/blog (which Wordpress doesn't currently give tools for, while they do give tools for pointing a subdomain at it). Am I misunderstanding how a 301 redirect works?.

Comment: If you are trying to leverage the blog in order to improve the root domains ranking, it is most beneficial to host the blog at mydomain.com/blog.

Comment: Check this out http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/ and hopefully that helps